How could the power to adjust the fundamental forces deal with antimatter attacks?
Context
The Scientocratic Hivemind can supernaturally strengthen or weaken the fundamental forces within atoms. It can influence the forces within a sphere of influence measuring 9,999 km. It can't manipulate the forces in any other way. It works through accumulation by influencing individual atoms until a qualitative change is achieved. It can't weaken a force to nonexistence but it can get close. It needs matter--and antimatter in this case--to operate with.
The Equilibrium Hivemind can create and manipulate antimatter(antiproton, positrons, etc.) versions of its target ex nihilo. If it is fighting a bunch of humans, it can summon a bunch of antimatter versions of the humans which it could then try to overlap with the regular matter humans. This 'mirroring' is arbitrary so the form of antimatter attacks are dependent on its target(which are humans in this case). It has a creation range of 1,101 km
Both are fighting in a vacuum. The Scientocratic Hivemind is constantly creating distance with its spaceship and the Equilibrium Hivemind is bridging the gap by boosting itself with the mass conversion of its antimatter.
Question
How could the power to strengthen or weaken the fundamental forces be able to neutralize the antimatter attacks such that it loses its threat?

You basically have magic already, what difference does it make? No one with any interest to science will find it compelling in any way. "manipulate antimatter versions of its target" - pointless. At any contact the part that contacts will be converted into energy, e=mc^2 which would instantly destroy both copies. Antimatter copies make absolutely no sense.

"... at short and long range" - you're talking about fundamental forces within atoms and tactics for interpersonal combat here - are you talking nanometres, micrometres, millimetres, metres, kilometres, light seconds...?  (Personally, I don't want to be on or in space around a planet where packets of tens of kilos of antimatter are being thrown around.)

@KerrAvon2055 That's referencing effective range of influence. Stuff like if something's far enough, the superpower can't influence it.

@Dmyt: Physics and superpowers don't make sense in the same discussion. You may find it cool, but your question reveals you don't really understand what you're asking.

So, what is short range?  Or long range?  Give us numbers - tactics that could be used from one metre away and tactics used from 100 km away are going to have just a few differences.  All we know is what you've written.

I forgot to ask in the Sandbox... are we dealing with classical SciFi antimatter or science-based antiparticles like antiprotons and positrons?

@JBH The science-based ones

Never trust people to read through the comments. Please [edit] your post with clarifications. Thanks.

It is a very funny question, imagine a sci-fi short story to advertise popular science! The close and down votes are essentially bad here. You are clearly misunderstood the question.

Btw, effect of antimatter to matter is not that they disappear. Effect of antimatter to matter is that they explode, roughly like a nuclear bomb. Roughly 1g of matter/antimatter makes a nuclear bomb like the Hiroshima one.

Let's see
First, let's look at just how ludicrous an antipersonnel weapon we are looking at here.  0.5 g of antimatter will mutually annihilate 0.5 g of normal matter to release 21.5 kT equivalent of energy.  So, adding 5 orders of magnitude for a smallish 50 kg person and 50 kg of antimatter person means the release of over 2 GT equivalent of energy, all in gamma rays.  Note that this is almost 3 orders of magnitude more powerful than Tsar Bomba...
In practice the initial explosion will not be that great - as the surface layers of atoms interact they will explode violently and disperse the rest of the antimatter as a hazard to everything in a very large area.  While the question states that this occurs in a vacuum, I'm going to assume inner orbits of a solar system - ie roughly 5 atoms per cc.  This will probably result in the 2 GT occurring in a vast number of smaller explosions as it hits interplanetary gas over a sphere of approximately 20,000 km diameter.  Alternatively, if it is in vacuum but on a body with a significant gravity well then expect a smaller but still large volume of the surface to be bombarded as gravity pulls fragments back down.
Note that 20,000 km diameter puts the attacker with a range of 1,101 km well within the sphere of irradiation of their own weapon.  If they are really unlucky then a decent sized fragment (eg 0.01 g) of antimatter will impact them directly and lethal doses of gamma radiation will be the least of their worries.
However, let's assume that the EH are determined to use the most ludicrous overkill possible to attack individuals instead of, for example, becoming a K1 civilisation overnight and building antimatter-fuelled starships.  Let's also assume that the SH have sensors that can detect the creation of antimatter men and sufficient reaction speed.  Among their options are:

Strengthen the gravitational force, collapse the antimatter being into a black hole and keep it that way.  Normally a micro-black hole would evaporate quickly due to Hawking radiation, but the SH can just keep their gravity-enhancing mojo on it until it has passed through its target.  A person-sized black hole is many orders of magnitude too small to cause gravitational tidal effects as it passes through a person (or a planet) and too small to have any realistic chance of impacting any particle as it passes through.  Even if the micro-black hole does capture a single particle, it will not do any noticeable damage.
Weaken the strong nuclear force on one side of the body to create a breach.  Assuming matter is expelled through the breach, this will make the antimatter body into a rocket.  Obviously, you do not want the main body or the exhaust stream to hit anything friendly as both are extremely dangerous.

In practice, both entities should aim to avoid a zero-sum game and team up to exploit their vast abilities to break the laws of conservation of mass-energy.  However, if they are antagonistic then expect a war of annihilation with one side collapsing the other into gravitational singularities before they can get into range to annihilate everything with antimatter.

Side note: proton is a compound particle of quarks. The quark and antisquark do not annihillate in the same moment, thus a baryon-antibaryon meet creates gammas, pions and antipions. Pions decay to neutrinos quite often. Result is that about 60% of the explosion will happen in the neutrino world. Probably too big explosion could not happen because there is no way to the keep the matter and the antimatter guy together while they have already started to react. I think you must shot them together with nearly light speed in an accelerator.

I show you a trick, how can you construct the logic of both sides, while you were not ever such a fundamental-interaction-manipulator hivemind, neither antimatter-version-cloning hivemind.
But it is not clear, how can Sciento (the interaction-strength manipulator) create distance. I see no trivial way to alter distances by altering interaction strengths in pure vacuum.
However, you can probably create matter by altering interaction strengths, simply because by doing that, also you create a lot of energy. Most of the matter you see around, are in a very fine-tuned equilibrium. Altering fundamental constants, even a little bit, would have disastrous effects.
For example: the deuterium nucleus is kept together by the strong force, but only very weakly. Somehow quanum numbers and energy level happen so together that the deuteron is very close to split to its parts (a proton and a neutron). If the strong interaction would be weaker even by a tenth percent, it would happen.
To the opposite, if the strong force would be a little bit stronger, then also the deuteron would be more stable - but not only it, but also the diproton! Diproton is a nucleus not existing in our world, it would be two proton connected. Protons distract each other electrically as the same charge, but the always attractive strong nuclear attracts them. Also diproton is on the border of stability, but it is on the unstable side. If the strong interaction would be even a little bit stronger, the diproton would be stable.
Now, imagine that your body has about 40% water and 1/6000 of the hydrogen in your body is deuterium. If the diproton is stable, protons can unite to it like in a hydrogen bomb. If the deuteron is unstable, your deuteron content would explode like a hydrogen bomb. Choose, how do you want to die.
It was only a single example, but there are many similars. Altering the fundamental interaction strengths is effectively a deus ex machina, similar to the creatio ex nihilio anti-matter construction.
I show you an algorithm, how to construct their battle.

You have the basic situation, to Sciento is fighting in his spaceship the Equilibrium guy.
Think, what could Equilibrium guy do now, what would be his best.
Assume that Sciento knows this, and expects Equilibrium to do that.
Think, that would be Scientos best option to fight it.
Assume that he is doing that.
Assume that Equilibrium knows, how will Sciento defense.
Go to 2.

Yes, the options will explode, and you will have a nearly infinite ways to explain to your readers about physics. You can safely keep the "Sci knows what Equi knows that Sci knows" track.
